# Match various Ids against a index within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to translate this line of Javascript code to Jquery. The problem i'm having is how do I get `i` to be incorporated in the jquery statement

```
for (var i = 0; i < game.BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        document.getElementById("pos" + i).addEventListener("click", game.MakeMove, false);
```

I know that I want to use the click() function, but my problem is incorporating the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an element by ID in jquery, use the selector `#id`. It can be a constructed string that you pass to the jquery function, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < game.BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
    $('#pos' + i).click(function(e) {
        game.MakeMove();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about the last parameter of `.addEventListener()` (true/false) though.
*Maybe* you should use `e.stopPropagation()` after the call to `MakeMove()` to fully translate your javascript addEventListener call.

Further reading:

- [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [About event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)
- [About event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: lol, I was thinking something along those lines, I guess I was over complicating the problem